# React this.context is undefined and I cannot access my AuthContext functions

Tags: reactjs

I have an AuthContext file that has several functions. I am trying to access these functions via context in another file using this.context.

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { Component, useContext, createContext } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext();

class AuthProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        user: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
        this.setState({ user });
    }

    getUser = () => {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    }

    userIsAuthenticated = () => {
        let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
        if (!user) {
            return false;
        }
        user = JSON.parse(user);

        if (Date.now() > user.data.exp * 1000) {
            this.userLogout();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        const { user } = this.state;
        const { getUser, userIsAuthenticated, userLogin, userLogout } = this;

        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, getUser, userIsAuthenticated, userLogin, userLogout }}>
                {children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default AuthContext

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export { AuthProvider }
```

Login.js

```
class Login extends Component {
    static contextType = AuthContext;

    state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        isLoggedIn: false,
        isError: false,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const Auth = this.context;
        console.log(Auth);
        const isLoggedIn = Auth.userIsAuthenticated();
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn });
    }
```

Auth is undefined in Login.js and I cannot access userIsAuthenticated. I am new to React so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us where you render an `<AuthProvider>`, and how it relates to where you render a `<Login>`? (The AuthProvider needs to be farther up the component tree than the Login)

Comment: And you know what, that was the exact problem. I completely forgot to render the AuthProvider. Thank you for the comment.